# <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order> of application.xml not working in Wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: java, deployment, ejb-3.1, wildfly-8

I am migrating my application from **JBoss 6 AS** to **Wildfly 8.2.0** AS. It is an EAR application containing MBeans and EJBs. It is a multi-maven module project and MBeans are scattered across different sub modules and packaging is of type EJB and JAR for those modules. I cannot convert sub-modules containing MBeans as SAR deployment as they are tightly linked and packed as JAR.

I am using **jboss-service.xml** in META-INF folder of EAR to deploy and register MBeans. MBeans are dependent on EJBs and hence, EJBs need to be deployed first before JAR containing MBeans gets deployed.

I tried `<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>` in **application.xml** to have an order in deployment of EAR contents but it is not following the modules sequence present in **application.xml** but it is not working. Order of deployment as defined in **application.xml** is not followed. FYI that I am unpacking the EAR and deploying using `auto-deploy-exploded="true"` in **deployment scanner** in **standalone-full-ha.xml**. I believe packed or unpacked EAR deployment format does not contribute this problem.

I also saw the xsd file of **jboss-app.xml** but I could not find any example supporting the order of EAR deployment.

Could anyone please help to implement the order of deployment for EAR in **Wildfly 8.2.0 AS**.

Answer (score 0):

There was this bug when defining the loading order in that certain module which depends on persistence unit declared in another module.

Removing the `<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>` worked for me on JBOSS EAP 6.4.